# JS Function counter doesn't output the correct numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Two digits are missing at the end, why? [Javascript output is in white and the desired numbers are in black above](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qn5a6alln7aeakh/Screenshot%202017-06-28%2011.52.48.png?dl=0).

[image]

Js Code:

```
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(now);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to upload this image here, do not post external links. At least, it is inconvenient. As for me, I have dropbox blocked by proxy server and cannot help you.

Comment: Two digits are missing at the end of what?

Comment: Well one digit for 3.740 and two digits for 4.400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain trailing zeros choosing how much digit will be shown (with toFixed(n)). Three decimal in example below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.count').each(function () {

    if($(this).text() % 1 != 0){

    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function (now) {
              $(this).text(now.toFixed(3));
          }
      });

    }else{

     $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function (now) {
              $(this).text(now.toFixed(0));
          }
      });

    }

});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9319/

Comment: Then the other numbers are incorrect: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tk8u41hc0qo4czt/Screenshot%202017-06-28%2013.18.46.png?dl=0

Comment: I update my answer. I check if value is decimal or not and I use a different counter for each case

Answer (score -1):

Solved it using

```
$(this).text(valueOf(now));
```

instead of:

```
$(this).text(now);
```